# How can we justify $\psi(\textbf{r})\to\psi_{in}(\textbf{r})+\psi_{sc}(\textbf{r})$ at $|\textbf{r}|\to \infty$ but not at finite $|\textbf{r}|$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, scattering, boundary-conditions, s-matrix-theory

In quantum scattering theory, the outgoing wave at $|\textbf{r}|\to\infty$, scattered from a localized potential, can be written as $$\psi(\textbf{r})\to\psi_{in}(\textbf{r})+\psi_{sc}(\textbf{r})$$ where $\psi_{in}$ is the incident wave and $\psi_{sc}=\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}$ is the scattered wave. I understand that to write an expression for $\psi(\textbf{r})$ requires one to solve the Schrodinger equation with the potential $V(r)$ which is a formidable job.

But how can I justify the limit $\psi(\textbf{r})\to\psi_{in}(\textbf{r})+\psi_{sc}(\textbf{r})$ at $|\textbf{r}|\to \infty$ but not at finite $|\textbf{r}|$?

Comment: Perhaps you could say something about the boundary conditions?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the definition of "scattering."  "Scattering" is defined to mean that the scattered particle's wavefunction escapes to infinity.  But if the potential is very complicated, you could have a situation where, say, the particle initially "bounces off" it and starts traveling outward, but then "loops back" and starts moving inward again.  Such a process is perfectly possible, but it wouldn't be considered a "scattering" process because the particle can't actually escape to infinity, so it actually describes a *bound state*.  The requirement that the particle be moving radially outward *at infinity* is there to rule out weakly bound states like the one described above, where the particle has complicated dynamics near the potential origin.

Comment: What if the potential is repulsive? Then there is no bound state problem. Right? Can we claim then that $\psi(\textbf{r})\to\psi_{in}(\textbf{r})+\psi_{sc}(\textbf{r})$ holds for all values of $|\textbf{r}|$? @tparker

Comment: @SRS No.  The point is that $\psi_\text{in}({\bf r})$ and $\psi_\text{sc}({\bf r})$ are both solutions to the Schrodinger equation with *no* potential (and therefore by linearity their sum is as well).  The potential is assumed to fall off to zero far away from the origin, so in those regions these wavefunction is well approximated by those two wavefunctions.  But near the origin, the potential will be important and will modify the wavefunction in a nontrivial and potential-dependent way.

Comment: @SRS Consider the simpler situation of scattering in one-dimension - e.g. calculating the reflection and transmission coefficients.  We can imagine a complicated potential near $x = 0$, but for a scattering problem we usually assume it is localized and vanishes far away from the origin.  Then the incoming, reflected, and transmitted waves have the simple form $e^{\pm ikx}$, but near the origin the potential distorts the wavefunction and makes it much more complicated.  A 3D scattering problem is very similar to calculating the reflection coefficient $R$, but more complicated because ...

Comment: ... it can depend on the angular direction.